# Action won't go away!

Tags: edit-mode

This is very annoying. I need to delete an action I keep hitting x and clear animation data and all that, won't leave! I have quit and reopened, there is no 0 next to the name.

Comment: there is another user of this action , you are just unlinking the action from this object

Comment: So how to remove completely?

Comment: i don't know the easy way but for python `bpy.data.actions['my action'].user_clear()` and restart

Comment: do you know a way without code?

Comment: sorry , i don't

Comment: @AidanPallian Try hitting X icon  while holding Shift button and then save and reopen.

Comment: @Denis Add that as an answer :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To unlink datablocks from the blend file hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> button and click on the **X** icon of the datablock. That will set the number of users to zero and it will not be saved in the blend file.

Remember to reload file after saving it.

[image]

Comment: it doesnt work.

Comment: @ThePoet Did you save the blend file and reload it after that?

Comment: @AdrianPallan Check to see if  they are "stashed" in the NLA editor, if so open the NLA editor and delete them from there.  This is a new behaviour & replaces the why are my actions lost, if a fake user wasn't added.

Comment: Does not work, the action is still there after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

here you can use this version of blender and holding shift while pressing the x (next to the animation in the action editor) will remove the fake user
not sure what changed between the updates but i know this one works

blender version 2.69
http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.69/