# Actions wont delete. Even with Shift+X

Tags: dopesheet

I am holding shift and hitting the "X" button in the action editor. The "0" doesn't show up. Please help :(
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ZiQtohl3tmbVlMZDFkYWc0TU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you try to save the file and reload?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. You asked this before here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30704/action-wont-go-away

Comment: I tried shift x. didn't you read my question? That old one was answered with shift x

Comment: Because the question is still asking the same thing you will likely get the same answers posted as that solution should work. On the other question you said the solution did work for you. If it doesn't, you should comment on the answer of the other question or edit your other question to say what you tried.

Comment: But what do I do?

Comment: @AdrianPallan Check to see if they are "stashed" in the NLA editor, if so open the NLA editor and delete them from there. This is a new behaviour & replaces the why are my actions lost, if a fake user wasn't added  (doubled up on this comment, posted it in answer on other thread should have been on question, sorry)

Comment: Clicked with Shift and [get 0 users](http://i.imgur.com/snxYGEO.jpg). After reload actions were gone. Used 2.75a version

Comment: Alright but it didn't work for me

Comment: Is there a setting I might have hit so I have to delete it in the nla editor?